Spring 3.4.0 Upgrade: Multiple Bean Definition Issue with Generic Repository in Abstract Service
After upgrading to Spring 3.4.0, I encountered a bean injection issue in a generic abstract service class. Here's the relevant code:
Repository Interface:
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface DemoRepository<T extends BaseEntity> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
    // Common repository methods (if any)
}

Service Implementation:
@Transactional
public abstract class DemoServiceImpl<T extends BaseEntity> implements DemoService<T> {

    @Autowired
    private DemoRepository<T> repository;

    // Other methods and logic
}

The application throws the following error during startup:

Field repository in com.example.service.impl.DemoServiceImpl required a single bean, but 5 were found:
userRepository
productRepository
orderRepository
- ...

This may be due to missing parameter name information.
Details:
The DemoRepository is a generic repository extended by several specific repositories in the project (e.g., UserRepository, ProductRepository, etc.).
Before upgrading to Spring 3.4.0, this setup worked perfectly, and the correct repository was injected based on the generic type T.
After the upgrade, Spring fails to determine which bean should be injected due to the presence of multiple repository beans.
What I've Tried:
Adding @Qualifier — Works, but is impractical for dynamic generic scenarios.
Refactoring the service to avoid generics — Involves significant changes across the project.
Checking the release notes for Spring 3.4.0 — No obvious changes related to this issue.

I think it something that is related to Spring 6. I am upgrading a large project from Spring 5 to Spring 6 and some tests are failing due to generic interfaces. Some tests could be fixed using @Qualifier but (in my case) not all.
